# How to edit a layout through a View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, view

In my project, I have access to a `View` that I want to edit, but **I do not have its layout XML file**. I know that I can replace the `View` by a customized one by inflating a custom layout, but I prefer just to edit it and try to add a simple `TextView` at the left part of it.

This is how I got access to that `View`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return view;
}
```

This is the `View` that I can get:

[image]

This is what I want to edit:

[image]

How can I access to its layout, or how can I edit it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add TextView From layout xml file.

Comment: But how can I add it without varying the original View?

Comment: if you want to add `TextView` Dynamically from Adapter then you need to get Parent View and then add accordingly .Add your Layout XML  file along with question.

Comment: Ok, but as I stated before, I do not have the XML file of that view... My question is if I can access to that XML file through the parent View.

Comment: If you Do not have an XML them you Should add Dynamically  in Parent View.

Comment: Oh... Please, could you tell me what I should do in order to add dynamically that numbers in the Parent View? A brief example of code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below method from your getView ():

```
private  View addTextView(View view){

    int TEXT_VIEW_ID=2;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(view.getContext());

    TextView textView = new TextView(relativeLayout.getContext());
    textView.setId(TEXT_VIEW_ID);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START|RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams1.addRule(TEXT_VIEW_ID,RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
    relativeLayout.addView(view);
    return relativeLayout;
}
```

Change your `getView()` method like below code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
// add method here like below line
    return addTextView(view);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it later!

Comment: Another little question. I managed to dynamically edit each element of the list by calling getChilAt(index). The problem is that I need to set the modified verison of the child again to its position inside the parent View. I need a kind of setChildAt(index) method... How can I do it?

Comment: Now you have parent Relative Layout and it has two Childs ,TextView and your Old Parent . So first you need to get Your Old Parent from realtive layout from index 1 and then your old logic apply same as .

Comment: **This solution is wrong** ... it will create addoner view for every call of get view ... so if convertView is used 4 times then it will have 4 addoner views

Comment: If you have batter solution please add with your comments.